# How to declare in Angular 17 a signal in class interface?

Tags: angular

In my class my properties should be signals, so far so good.

```
 public varName =signal('');
```

But I like to use the related interface also, but I could not find any documentation or a solution to implement the property correctly in the interface.
I get only:

> TS2416: Property varName in type VariableUnitBuilder is not assignable to the same property in base type IVariableUnitBuilder
> Type WritableSignal is not assignable to type string

Comment: what do you mean by "related interface"?

Comment: related interface, I mean the interface, which must gbe implemented by the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
interface Var {
  varName: ReturnType<typeof signal<string>>
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ varName() }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App implements Var {
  varName = signal('Angular');
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3yczw6)